# Is exponential map, $X \mapsto e^X$ for matrices injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

As I know, exponential function is strictly monotonic increasing function. So it means that for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $e^x=e^y$ then $x=y$. But how about exponential matrix? If I have two matrices $X,Y$ satisfy $e^X=e^Y$, does that mean $X=Y$?

Comment: by the way, I edited the title to properly reflect what you asked in the question (unique isn't the word you were looking for, the correct term in this context is injective)

Comment: Ahh thanks @peek-a-boo.

Comment: No it does not. Check out the zero matrix and the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(2i\pi, 0)$

Comment: also, you should specify whether you're interested in matrices with only real entries, or whether you allow for complex entries